# Получить данные с помощью Intent из адаптера

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity

Имеется адаптер

```
public class TAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Trenirovka> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private int layout;
private ArrayList<Trenirovka> trenirovkaList;
MainActivity m = new MainActivity();

public TAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Trenirovka> trenirovka) {
    super(context, resource, trenirovka);

    this.trenirovkaList = trenirovka;
    this.layout = resource;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(this.layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    final Trenirovka trenirovka = trenirovkaList.get(position);

    viewHolder.nameView.setText("Id:"+trenirovka.getID() + " Name: " + trenirovka.getName());
    viewHolder.parView.setText(formatValue(trenirovka.getPar_one(), trenirovka.getPar_two(), trenirovka.getPar_three(), trenirovka.getPar_fore()));


    viewHolder.loadbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent bf = new Intent();
            bf.putExtra("id", trenirovka.getID());
            bf.putExtra("name", trenirovka.getName());
            bf.putExtra("par1", trenirovka.getPar_one());
            bf.putExtra("par2", trenirovka.getPar_two());
            bf.putExtra("par3", trenirovka.getPar_three());
            bf.putExtra("par4", trenirovka.getPar_fore());


            Intent a = new Intent(TAdapter.this.getContext(), AcLoad.class);
            viewHolder.loadbutton.getContext().startActivity(a);
        }
    });

    viewHolder.addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

private String formatValue(int par_one, int par_two, int par_three, int par_ofore) {
    return String.valueOf(par_one) + ", " + String.valueOf(par_two) + ", " + String.valueOf(par_three) + ", " + String.valueOf(par_ofore);
}

private class ViewHolder {
    final Button addButton, loadbutton;
    final TextView nameView, parView;

    ViewHolder(View view) {
        addButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        loadbutton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.loadbutton);
        nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameView);
        parView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.parView);

    }
}
```

}

В методе **viewHolder.loadbutton.setOnClickListener** получаю данные и пытаюсь передать их и запустить другую активность , но вот другая активность не принимает , через логи пишет что все значения равны null , на основной активности данные выводятся в логи правильно , но почему то не отправляются на другую , не понимаю что не так ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не тот интент используете для запуска активити. Вообще студия должна вам подсвечивать проблемные места, а именно то, что интент, который вы наполнили данными, вы в дальнейшем не используете, а создаёте новый и именно его запускаете.

Таким образом вам надо запускать активити именно тем интентом, в который вы данные кладёте. Т.е.:

```
Intent bf = new Intent(TAdapter.this.getContext(), AcLoad.class);
bf.putExtra("id", trenirovka.getID());
bf.putExtra("name", trenirovka.getName());
bf.putExtra("par1", trenirovka.getPar_one());
bf.putExtra("par2", trenirovka.getPar_two());
bf.putExtra("par3", trenirovka.getPar_three());
bf.putExtra("par4", trenirovka.getPar_fore());

viewHolder.loadbutton.getContext().startActivity(bf);
```

---

Также, как помянуто в другом ответе, можно передавать не отдельные поля, но целиком объект, заставив его реализовывать `Serializable` или `Parcelable`.

---

И опасайтесь хардкода ключей - опечатаетесь случайно и будете часами отлаживать ища проблему. Используйте константы для ключей.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , помогло)

Answer (score 2):

Для подобной задачи можно использовать интерфейс `Serializable` или `Parcelable`. Рекомендуют использовать последний. 
Пример:

```
public class Training implements Parcelable
```

Cкладываем данные в интент:

```
    public static final String EXTRA_TRAINING = "training";

    Training training = new Training();
    training.setId(123);
    //...

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TRAINING, training);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Вторая активность должна получить данные так:

```
Training training = (Training)getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_TRAINING);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , Serializable буду позже разбирать , с Intent надо до конца разобраться)